# c++ - How can I delete a undeclared pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, delete-operator

If the `new` operator was written in a function argument or constructor argument like:

```cpp
Foo* f = new Foo(new Baz(0, 0));
// how to delete "new Baz(0, 0)"?
delete f;
```

I know it can be written to:

```cpp
Baz* b = new Baz(0, 0)
Foo* f = new Foo(b);
delete b;
delete f;
```

But it became complicated, is there any better way?

Should I do something like this:

```cpp
Class Foo {
private:
    Baz* _b;
public:
    Foo(Baz* b) : _b(b) {}
    ~Foo() {
        delete _b;
    }
}
// so that when I delete foo will also delete baz;
```

Comment: `delete` should be called by the one who owns the memory. If you are looking for best solution - do not use `new` at all, use smart pointers instead and these troubles will go away. Or use values, if there is no need for pointers, as there does not seem to be for `Baz` in `Foo`.

Comment: What about giving to `Foo` only the `Baz` parameters instead ? So that `Foo` will own its internal `Baz` properly (it will construct it and delete it). Actually it depends on your real use case, do you need to create that `Baz` explicitly outside ? Etc... There is rarely a "better" thing in the general case, it often depend on the use-case.

Comment: "[S]hould I do something like [this]"... Either that (while also following [the rules of three or five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)). ***Or*** use `std::unique_ptr` for both pointers and follow the rule of zero.

Comment: Your solution is generally a good way to go. But, note that: 1) `Foo` has the auto-generated copy constructor/assignment operator that performs a shallow copy. 2) Prefer smart pointer when dealing with ownership. 3) AFAIK, `new Foo(new Baz(0, 0))` may lead to resource leaks in case of exceptions.

Comment: I would think in terms of **ownership**, not of "calling new and delete". Who *owns* `b`? The answer to that will decide how your `Foo` class will be designed. It would be easier to discuss this with real world examples, because the motivations for the decisions depend on how it's used. `Foo` and `Baz` are meaningless therefore there's no motivating factor to choose one design over another.

Comment: `is there any better way?` YES: [std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my own recommendation about the rule of zero and using `std::unique_ptr`, I would do something like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a, int b)
        baz_{ std::make_unique<Baz>(a, b) }
    {
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<Baz> baz_;
};
```

And

```
auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>(0, 0);
```

With this the `foo` object *own* its own unique `Baz` object.

---

If you want `Foo` to by copyable then use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared` instead.

Answer (score 1):

More or less Yes, you should delete an allocated field in the destructor.

If the class has children, make the destructor `virtual`.

However you could have passed an existing pointer. And then the field is not owned.

You can use one of the ptr classes, i.e. `std::unique_ptr` for the `Baz`.

Or defer the deletion to the caller in some form:

```
Baz* _b; // Or Baz _b.
Foo(const Baz& b) : _b(new Baz(b)) {} // When feasible a copy.
```

From design point it would